# GPIO LED is constantly on. GPIOZero can't turn it off

Tags: gpio, led, gpiozero

If power is supplied to the Pi then the LED will be on by default. I've got the LED connected to GPIO pins [4, 6] and the script can not turn it off. I've switch the cables around and that's resulted in the same LED behavior.

Here's the code:

```py
from gpiozero import LED
from time import sleep

i = 0

while True:
    red = LED(i)
    print("Attempting to turn off: ", i)
    red.off()
    sleep(1)
    i+=1
    if i > 30:
        exit(1)
```

Comment: Physical pin 4 is not a GPIO pin. It's a 5V pin and cannot be switched. See https://pinout.xyz/

Comment: Connecting from 4 to 1 has wielded the same result? Am I still interpreting things incorrectly?

Comment: Pin 1 isn't a GPIO either. Look for a pinout diagram, choose a GPIO pin and connect to that.

Comment: Thank you! That's got everything working as intended. Thanks both of you :)